# Maximum cardinality of separated sets in the Hamming distance

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, coding-theory

This question is motivated by section 15.1 (Codes) of Alon and Spencer's *The probabilistic method*.

Fix $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\{0,1\}^n$ be the length $n$ binary strings with the Hamming distance.

Let $N_n$ be the maximal cardinality of a $\alpha n$-separated set (that is, the points of the set are pairwise at distance $\alpha n$) in $\{0,1\}^n$. What do we know about the growth rate of $N_n$?

It has to grow slower than $\frac{2^n}{\#B(0,\frac{n\alpha}{2})}$. So, as $\#B(0,\frac{n\alpha}{2})=2^{n(H(\frac{\alpha}{2})+o(1))}$ (where $H(x)=-x\log_2(x)-(1-x)\log_2(1-x)$), as proved in the section mentioned above of Alon and Spencer's book, this gives an upper bound of $2^{n(1-H(\frac{\alpha}{2})+o(1))}$. I don't think I have any decent lower bounds.

Comment: There are better bounds, like Elias - Bassalygo, based on considering slightly large balls that may intersect but not by many balls at once: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_Bassalygo_bound

Comment: fixed the link in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best upper bound will depend on $\alpha.$ and also whether you are interested in asymptotics.

There is a nice short chapter describing some of what is known [https://algo.epfl.ch/_media/en/courses/2008-2009/mct_l03.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffd8x.jpg). The quantity $\alpha_2(x)$ is what you are interested in. In general unless $\alpha$ is very small the best upper bound is the so-called MRRW (4 Americans) bound of McEliece-Rudemich-Rumsey-Welch obtained by linear programming.

The lower bound given is Gilbert-Varshamov, and all the others are upper bounds. There have been some limited improvements on it, see [Jiang and Vardy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404325.pdf) which I believe has since appeared in the IEEE Transactions on Information Theory after Alex Vardy unexpectedly passed away.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I think the first "here" from your answer point to the wrong link?